# Matlab: Generate distance matrix of N points

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graph

I am trying to efficiently generate a distance matrix of around 200.000 2D points, but somehow I am feeling that my trivial approach of using for loops with `pdist` is not efficient enough -- my idea was to manually create a lower triangular matrix containing the distances.

In the end the aim is to generate a minimal spanning tree from the 2D point data using `graphminspantree`. Is there any recommended way to solve this problem? Maybe even a builtin function I simply couldn't find? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As requested, here is a minimal working example

```
G = [2,3;3,4;4,5];
D = zeros(length(G), length(G));
for col = 1:length(G)
    for row = (col+1):length(G)
        D(row, col) = pdist(cat(1, G(col,:), G(row,:)), 'euclidean');
    end
end
disp(D);
```

In other languages, there are ways of generating the required numbers on the fly; it is called stream programming. E.g. Sage or Scala have methods to generate lists on the fly. Is there something comparable in Matlab? I am quite new to Matlab.

For example, you could generate the fibonacci sequence like this in Scala on demand:

```
val fibs: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fibs.scanLeft(1)(_ + _)
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: A full distance matrix would be of size 1/2 * 2e5 * 2e5 = 2e10 doubles, which in storage takes up some 18GB. Seems like a lot...

Comment: @m.s. I have added a minimal working example now.

Comment: @Adriaan exactly, that is one of the reasons why I am asking for different solutions. I have updated my question to reflect. Is there something like stream programming?

Comment: Well, the question then is what you want to do with these numbers. If you only need one distance at a time, you can of course calculate one distance at a time. If, however, you want to do full interpolation, e.g. Kriging, you need all those distances at once. Then you'll want to look at discarding the 90% or so furthest points to shrink size per iteration point, of course at the cost of computational time. Initial downsampling might be the way to go, at a cost of resolution.

Comment: @Adriaan I need all distances in order to generate a minimal spanning tree from the data; reducing the sample count is not an option. Are there other ways to produce a minimal spanning tree from the data? Either you precalculate a lower triangular matrix containing the distances, or you calculate them on the fly (but then you will calculate the "same" distance multiple times) ... Lazy evaluation + caching would probably be best, but I have no idea how this could work in Matlab.

Comment: Sure, as I said, it's either a huge load on RAM, or a much longer calculation time. Depends entirely on your system. If you have 64GBs of RAM, go for the full matrix, if you don't, go for calculating it step by step. You might also want to consider using [octrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

Comment: The problem is that even with lazy evaluation, at some point you're going to have 100,000 vertices **in** the spanning tree and 100,000 vertices **outside** the tree (assuming Prim's, for the sake of argument). You will either have to have a 100,000x100,000 distance matrix in memory, or you will have to have a min_distance for each of the 100,000 vertices not in the tree and update them all when the 100,001st vertex is added to the tree.

Comment: @Adriaan thanks for pointing out octrees; I've heard of them, but never used them before.

Comment: @beaker Originally I wanted to use [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) for the problem, but I guess it won't make a huge difference. I guess there really aren't any other feasible possibilities after all; I thought maybe there is some fancy algorithm I simply wasn't aware of that might elegantly and efficiently solve this problem.

Comment: The problem with Kruskal is that initially you have to have all of the |V|^2 edges available to search. Since you can't hold all of them in memory, you'll need to generate them on the fly. O(|V|) times. That's going to take a long time.

Comment: @beaker Exactly. Therefore, I am using sparse matrices and an entirely different approach now, including Delaunay triangulation. I am going to post a solution, when I've got one.